# Is sending a lot of mails considered spam?

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, email-spam

Is sending a total of 1.3 million e-mails (around 2 every second) considered spam?

The contents of the mail are normal, not fishy/scammy whatever. It's an email containing regular information.

Comment: That's far too broad question for SO. You certainly can send that many messages (I do, often, and at far higher rates), but it takes a lot of time and expertise to get up to that kind of level.

Answer (score 0):

If they are double opt-in emails that signed up to received email from you. Then it's not considered spam in the eyes of the law.

Now every spam filtering software of every domain has their own definition of what they will consider spam.

Think about it, Amazon, Ebay, and many others sends millions of emails a day. If you start out sending 1 million emails and you never sent an email before from your IP addresses you're going to run into issues at some ESP. It takes time for the spam filters to recognize your IP's and to [warm up](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/warmingips/) to them.